# Anaconda Python Translate

Tags: python, anaconda, translate

Hi I just want to translate text to english. I am using anaconda, its translating on cmd python foo.py but It gives error on anaconda setup.

```
from googletrans import Translator
translator=Translator()
translator.translate("jumps over")
```

And It says

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
##EDIT
I tryed but same Error occured

from googletrans import Translator
translator=Translator()
print(translator.translate("this is a good example").text)
But 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I think that `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'` output happens if your code doesn't output anything if I remember correctly. I tried this:

```
from googletrans import Translator
translator=Translator()
print(translator.translate("こんにちは"))
```

and the code seems to work just fine, try to print out whatever the function returns.

Comment: I tryed but same Error occured

Comment: Is there any another way to translate text

Comment: I don't see why you would get this error if i'm completely honest, maybe there is some problem with Anaconda. Do you have more code in your script or is this all?

Comment: Its all of it,  pip install translate ,  conda install -c auto translate and more like this I installed but anaconda is not working